pointwise convergence of cdf's, proof of arcsine law for wiener process from simple random walk using donkster invariance principle
Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be iid random variables $P(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{2}=P(X_i=-1)$ and let $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ be simple random walk. Let $M_{2n}$ be the first time of hitting maximum in the walk of $2n$ steps. One of the arcsine laws for simple random walks states precisely that for $0<a<b<1$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(a\leq \frac{M_{2n}}{2n}\leq b)=\int_a^b\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$ (in Durret for instance).
I am trying to prove analogue of this theorem for Wiener process using Donsker's invariance principle and in particular I want to show that $\frac{M_{2n}}{2n}$ converges in distribution to arcsine distribution (then I will be done with the proof). Since arcsine distribution have density $\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$ it suffices to show that $F_n(t)$ converges to $F(t)$ pointwise, where $F_n$ and $F$ are cdf's of $\frac{M_{2n}}{2n}$ and arcsine distribution respectively. I thought it would be possible and easy since $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(a\leq \frac{M_{2n}}{2n}\leq b)=\int_a^b\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$, however I have a problem because $$F_n(t)=P(\frac{M_{2n}}{2n}\leq t)=P(0\leq \frac{M_{2n}}{2n}\leq t)$$ and limit does not work for $a=0$ (in the statement od theorem for random walks). If I could interchange order of limits like that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(F_n(t)-F_n(0))=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{a \to 0}P(a\leq \frac{M_{2n}}{2n}\leq t)=\lim_{a \to 0}\lim_{n\to \infty}P(a\leq \frac{M_{2n}}{2n}\leq t)=\int_a^b \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}dx$$ I would be done since I believe $F_n(0)$ converges to $0$. But I don't know how to justify interchange of limits, I don't even know if it is possible.
I know there are plenty ways to prove this differently but I want this way or similarly short different way. Any suggestion is welcomed though.

You have $\lim_n (F_n(b)-F_n(a))=\int_a^b {1\over\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx$ for all $0<a<b<1$. But
$$
F_n(b) \ge F_n(b)-F_n(a),
$$
so
$$
\liminf_n F_n(b)\ge\int_a^b {1\over\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx,\quad\forall a\in(0,b).
$$
Let $a\downarrow 0$ to see that
$$
\liminf_n F_n(b)\ge\int_0^b {1\over\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx.
$$
Now play the same game in the other direction: Given $b\in(0,1)$ fix (for the moment) $c\in(b,1)$; then
$$
F_n(b)\le 1-(F_n(c)-F_n(b)).
$$
Let $n\to\infty$:
$$
\limsup_n F_n(b)\le 1-\int_b^c {1\over\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx;
$$
and finally let $c\uparrow 1$:
$$
\limsup_n F_n(b)\le 1-\int_b^1 {1\over\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx=
\int_0^b {1\over\pi\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\,dx.
$$
